# Fill Table View with JSON

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, exc-bad-access

Here goes a newbie question:

1. Create a new project in Xcode: `File > New Project` and select **Navigation-based Application** from iPhone OS templates.
2. Install `json-framework` as explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/wiki/InstallationInstructions#Option_1:_Copy_the_JSON_source_files_into_your_project).
3. Edit `RootViewController.h`'s interface section into this:

   ```
   @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
       NSURLRequest *request;
       NSURLConnection *theConnection;
       NSMutableData *receivedData;
       NSArray *faculties;
   }
   ```
4. Edit `RootViewController.m` and [implement a couple of simple things](http://pastebin.com/N1PyGLTw). Replace `<your_domain_name_goes_here>` with a valid domain name where a web service will answer to your calls.
5. URL above will output a JSON string [like this](http://pastebin.com/cwyFLviV).
6. Now, if you build&run this code, in debugger console you'll get:

   ```
   Attaching to process 35594.
   2010-07-19 13:15:31.307 WSMobileTest[35594:207] Succeeded! Received 580 bytes of data
   Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
   ```

**Any ideas?**

Developer Information:

```
Version:        3.2 (10M2262)
Location:       /Developer
Applications:
    Xcode:              3.2.3 (1688)
    Interface Builder:  3.2.3 (788)
    Instruments:        2.7 (2529)
    Dashcode:           3.0.1 (330)
SDKs:
    Mac OS X:
        10.5:   (9L31a)
        10.6:   (10M2262)
    iPhone OS:
        3.2:    (7B367)
        4.0:    (8A293)
    iPhone Simulator:
        3.2:    (7W367a)
        4.0:    (8A293)
```

Comment: Exalted:

What are you building to (3.2 or 4.0)?
What line are you getting the exception from? (Check with debugging)

- Frank

Comment: Also, line 76 should be:
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[receivedData bytes] length:[receivedData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: @Frank iPhone OS Deployment Target is "iPhone OS 4.0" and Base SDK is "iPhone Device 4.0"...

Second time when numberOfRowsInSection is called [faculties count] returns correct number of elements in array and then when code enters in cellForRowAtIndexPath debugger won't show no variables at all, therefore line 146 in RootViewController.m will block and debugger won't ever reach a breakpoint on line 147 as if continue button wouldn't have no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations: You've included everything except the line that causes the crash. Set a breakpoint and step through the debugger until it crashes, or look at the backtrace, or something.

In this case, I think you mean `faculties = [[jsonString JSONValue] retain;`.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I cannot make the app crash via debugger, but it won't step over and hang on line 146 in RootViewController.m, just as I did reply to Frank in reply to his comment to my original post.

As for "retain", due to my ignorance on Objective-C programming in general and iPhone programming in particular, I wasn't aware of what was going on. Thanks for your tip, I won't loose faculties variable therefore code will work without issues.